# C# Closing all windows but also being able to logout

Tags: c#, forms, window

I would like to be able to close all the windows in the application with the close button at the top right. However, I also have a logout function which only needs to close the current window. I cannot figure out how to do this because it either can close all the windows or only one - never both functions at the same time.

The way I'm currently doing it is like this:

```
private void buttonLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void MainMenu_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `Form.Closing Event`, not `Form.Closed`? and of course execute your logout function in the handler function.